# Setting a Preferred Network Adapter for browsing

Tags: browser, network-adapter

My PC at work is connected to 2 networks;

1. LAN: local corporate network for remote desktop access and very slow internet connection
2. WAN: wireless faster internet browsing

I need to be connected to both networks, but I want my internet browsing to use a specific one (WAN, because it is faster and no restriction). Is there a way to setup the default/preferred network adapter for the internet browsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this Microsoft article:
[How to change the binding order of network adapters in Windows XP and in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564)
(it still works in newer Windows versions)

> **How to change the binding order of network adapters**
>
> 1. Click Start, click Run, type ncpa.cpl , and then click OK.
>     You
>      can see the available connections in
>      the LAN and High-Speed Internet
>      section of the Network Connections
>      window.
> 2. On the Advanced menu, click Advanced Settings, and then click the
>      Adapters and Bindings tab.
> 3. In the Connections area, select the connection that you want to move
>      higher in the list. Use the arrow
>      buttons to move the connection.