# Prefer wired over wireless on same network (special case)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-adapter

In a related post ([multiple nics force routing](https://superuser.com/questions/455809/multiple-nics-force-routing)), I asked about forcing Internet traffic to go via one specific NIC where there were multiples.  In that case, the 100Mb wired network had no Internet connection and I needed to have internet traffic go via a mobile broadband WiFi device (in this case a HUAWEI E585).  I've been provided with a solution that works, by locating the place where Windows 7 stored the routing order for the adapters and adjusting accordingly.

What I didn't mention, in the previous post was the that the internal (wired) network was running out of a home based Wireless Router with both WiFi and Wired connections (Thomson TG782T).
OK, so if I have my laptop connected to the E585 and the wired connection to my internal network - all is fine.  However, if I now disconnect from the E585, I have my laptop set up to automatically connect to the TG782T by wireless (in the event that it isn't directly connected by CAT5 cable).

Because I have set the Laptop to prefer the WiFi adapter over the wired adapter, it seems to me that if I'm connected to the TG782T by both WiFi and Wired connections, the WiFi connection would be preferred.  Obviously, if I disconnect from the WiFi, the traffic will only be transferred by the wired connection.  But if I forget, is there any way I can set things up so that the Laptop (Windows 7) understands that if it is connected to the same network by both wired and WiFi - that it should prefer the wired connection?

I've noted other posts on the site with similar topics, but it seems to me that I don't have the same situation - since I've already intervened to make the wireless preferred over the wired (for purposes of ensuring internet connectivity).  For example, they mention that the routing metric for the wired connection should be lower than that for the wireless. but I've just checked mine and the values are: 10.0.0.10 (wireless) 25 and 10.0.0.30 (wired) 276 (possibly because of my re-ordering of the routing order).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking the same as "ala", Please have a look at this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/140218/setting-a-preferred-network-adapter-for-browsing)

And the suggested [URL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564) as well.

Comment: No, it's not... That's why I said I'd looked at the other posts.  My special case is:  Having decided that I want Wireless preferred over Wired specifically for Internet Connection; when I disconnect from the Internet and only have local connection (but via both wireless AND wired), I want Wired preferred.  It looks like a Catch-22 - but a sophisticated solution (such as some of the connection management apps) would allow me to do it.  I'm just trying to ascertain to what lengths I need to go to achieve the result I'm after.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, I made the change you suggest to achieve the result addressed in the previous post (above) - running ncpa.cpl and changing the routing order.  This current post behaviour (I believe) is a result of that since (I understand) Windows normally prefers wired over wireless for the same network.